# Magento keywords usefulness (SEO) when using Apache Solr as search engine

Tags: indexing, seo, solr, apache

I am studying implementing Solr as a search engine in a startup Magento store.

Since it's indexing the text in a (desirably) efficient way, the keywords I presume are irrelevant for the store indexing.

Can I bypass keywords at all ? What is the importance of keywords in this setup ? SEO only ?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: what keywords do you mean?

Comment: The ones you inform at the product creation, meta information tab.

Answer (score 1):

The keywords in the `Meta information` tab are there only for SEO reasons.

Most search engines will use these keywords to some degree. As far as I know it has no value for Solr by default.

**[Edit]** you can auto generate keywords from description the following way. It's based on the idea that the most important words occur the most. Depending on how you write the description this may or may not give any relevant results.

```
$description = $this->getDescription();
$words = explode("\s", $description); // explode to get all words
$occurrence = array_count_values($words); // get occurrence of words in order of most recurring
$occurrence = array_slice($occurrence, 0, 10); // limit to 10 words

$keywords = implode(', ', array_keys($occurrence)); // create a string from the 10 words
```

Comment: Is there any way to automate extraction of that keywords from the description text ?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you. About the algorithm it would be nice if it extracted the nouns at least, word occurrence is not a good measure in my sample texts.

Comment: No you're true, I tried to find the script I once wrote. It worked on large texts with a black list of words, On small texts it doesn't really work well I guess. If you find a better solution please share

Comment: I thought about attributes. I am setting up layered navigations with lots of user attributes, if I could just pick those options as keywords for the product (specifying which attributes to use) it would be great I think.

Comment: @Niloct On a hackathon this weekend we've build this: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/layered-landing It might work for you. Feel free to use it and let me know if you have questions or feedback